# How to change color multiple times with css-animations?

Tags: html, css-animations

I want to change the color of text with Css-animations multiple times infinitely.

```
<div class="footer-
widget-area">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm- 
6 footer-widget" 
role="complementary">
<div id="text-4" 
class="widget widget_text">          
<div class="textwidget"><p>. 
<a  href="http://4309.co.uk
/contact/">Contact</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#text-4 a{ animation: change 
1s forwards; animation-
delay: 11s;} 

@keyframes change 
{from{color:white;} to 
{color: 
blue;} to{color:yellow;}}
```

This doesn't work as second color `yellow`overides first color `blue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use with percentage like:

```css
#text-4 a{ animation: change 
3s forwards infinite; animation-delay: 5s;} 

@keyframes change 
{
0% { color: blue; }
25% { color: orange; }
50% { color: yellow; }
75% { color: black; }
100% { color: red; }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-
widget-area">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm- 
6 footer-widget" 
role="complementary">
<div id="text-4" 
class="widget widget_text">          
<div class="textwidget"><p>. 
<a  href="http://4309.co.uk
/contact/">Contact</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```